# How to change display banner for mobile view

Tags: css, banner

On home page I created simple banner with category product:
[image]

But on mobile view the banner looks bad. It displays the images one below the other and they are positioned on the left. I need it to display two images in one row.

I tried to use:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {

}
```

but the media-query also changed the view on desktop.

Comment: can u share the HTML

Comment: Yes, I try but when I paste here then I cannot approve subject because code is too long.  You can check source here: https://zabezcen.pl/source.html

Comment: In your source.html I can see the bootstrap classes but can't see the bootstrap CSS and js files. can u check whether you have included those in the file. If they present you can add "col-sm-6" instead of "col-sm-3" to get 2 columns in smaller devices

Comment: Ok, but how to use col-sm-3 for desktop, and example col-sm-6 for mobile view?

Comment: Here also you can see source file bootstrap: https://zabezcen.pl/bootstrapcopy.less

Comment: for desktops, you can use col-lg classes, read through the bootstrap documentation and you will get a clear idea about the breakpoints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190425/discussion-between-rajesh-and-sylvester).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mobile devices please add "col-6" along with other "col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12" classes and this will solve your issue since you are using the latest bootstrap version